# ORA-01658: Unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, schema, tablespace

I got message on Oracle when creating schema:

> ORA-01658: Unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace using application.

I have searched to solve this issue, but it is still not working.

Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace TS\_DATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071152/ora-01658-unable-to-create-initial-extent-for-segment-in-tablespace-ts-data)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the DBA privileges to resolve this problem.

See the [Oracle forum discussion](https://community.oracle.com/message/10499995).

> 1. extend the datafile to add space (`ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE <name> RESIZE <new size>`)
> 2. add a new datafile to the tablespace `(ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace name> ADD DATAFILE <datafile name>`

Comment: Thanks Rahul, for your information we have set when CREATE TABLESPACE and DATAFILE we set AUTOEXTEND. Is it we still need to RESIZE the DATAFILE and TABLESPACE ?

Comment: @user3354967:- Yes you need it.