# Oracle 10g data import

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, datapump

I am have a server which has oracle 10g installed. I have created dump of all the databases. I want to import those dumps into newly installed machine on which 10g is also installed. When I try to import dump it is giving error like below :

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist  
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "SYSTEM.SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_06"    
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95    
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 863    
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSTEM
```

Here is the command I am using

```
impdp SYSTEM/system SCHEMAS=test DUMPFILE=TEST.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace LOGFILE=test.log
```

Comment: Can you post your impdp command?

Comment: [Off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); but check that the user you're trying to run the import as has been given the necessary privileges.

Comment: impdp SYSTEM/system SCHEMAS=test DUMPFILE=TEST.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace LOGFILE=test.log

Comment: also tried with imp command where i have given the path to the .dmp file but it wasn't work too

Comment: The fact that the SYSTEM tablespace can not be extended is **alarming**. Did you store all user tables in the SYSTEM tablespace?

Answer (score 1):

The message seems quite clear.

```
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "SYSTEM.SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_06"    
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95    
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 863    
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSTEM
```

Datapump jobs are managed using master tables in the SYSTEM schema. There is not enough space in the SYSTEM tablespace to create the master table for this import job so the job fails.

You need to ask your DBA to increase the OS storage allocated to the SYSTEM tablespace. See this SO answer to [find out how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37071404/146325).

Comment: system is installed newly so there is no issue with space.

Comment: That's not what the error message says. There might be plenty of empty disk on the server, but the database can only use what's allocated to it. Clearly the SYSTEM tablespace has been allocated datafiles which are too small for your needs.

Comment: How can I increase that?

Comment: Linked to pertinent SO answer

Comment: that has been done but still after importing dump its not showing data

Comment: That seems like a completely different issue. Please ask a new question, including sample details from the datapump log, bad file, etc . In the meantime, as my answer appears to solved your first problem you should accept it. Questions with accepted answers improve the value of SO as a resource for future seekers.

Comment: after altering table space its having the same error

Comment: Afraid there's not much more I can do to help without hands on access to your environment