# Oracle segment space

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I have a Tablespace with some tables and I can insert data without problem. Now I want to create a new table and I get this:

> 1658. 00000 -  "unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace %s"
>         *Cause:    Failed to find sufficient contiguous space to allocate INITIAL
>                extent for segment being created.

My question is: if there is a space problem, why am I able to insert data but not create new tables?

This is the CREATE script:

```
CREATE TABLE EC_SYS_NOTIFY_KYC (
  ID NUMBER(38,0) PRIMARY KEY,  
  ID_OP NUMBER(38,0),
  PROCESS_ID VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,   
  SYSTEM_ID VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL)
TABLESPACE ECONTKYC_LARGE_1;
```

Comment: The problem is in: Failed to find sufficient **contiguous** space.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I´m not DB Admin. To deal with this problem should I request more space to the Admins? Or some type of defragmentation is necessary?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071152/ora-01658-unable-to-create-initial-extent-for-segment-in-tablespace-ts-data?answertab=active#tab-top) answer.

Comment: Show the source text of the sql `CREATE TABLE `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space in Oracle is allocated in chunks called 'extents'. Your existing tables have already been allocated extents containing enough space to allow inserts for now, but you don't have enough unallocated free space in the tablespace to add a whole new extent, which is needed for a new table.

Eventually inserts into existing tables will start to fail as well, when their existing space is used up and they need more.

Comment: Ok, understood. A resize request solved the problem. Many thanks William.